# How to do Polygon Spatial Search in Spring-data-solr

Tags: java, spring, solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I have to do a query something like below :-

`fq=latlng:IsWithin(POLYGON(('23.60 71.60','28.65 71.68','28.60 72.61','28.63 72.65')))`

Now I got stuck here in how to do this query using Spring-Data-Solr where I have function like

```
public List<Hotel> getHotelsInsidePolygon(Point... points);
```

It will be helpful if anyone tells how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this one :-

Thing to change in Solr for polygon search to work are

1. Add JTS jars in deployed solr war WEB-INF/lib
2. Change field type of latlng from **"location"** to **"location_rpt"**
3. Modify location_rpt field type as below

`<fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"
               spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
               distErrPct="0.025"
               maxDistErr="0.000009"
               units="degrees"
            />`

4. Add location data to index it and the polygon query will work.